# how to give tuple via command line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments

I have to input few parameters via command line. such as tileGridSize, clipLimit etc via command line. This is what my code looks like;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import sys #import Sys. 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread(sys.argv[1], 0) # reads image as grayscale
clipLimit = float(sys.argv[2])
tileGridSize = tuple(sys.argv[3])
clahe = cv.createCLAHE(clipLimit, tileGridSize)
cl1 = clahe.apply(img)

# show image
cv.imshow('image',cl1)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

if I pass the arguments like,below (I want to give (8, 8) tuple);

> > python testing.py picture.jpg 3.0 8 8

I get the following error. I understand the error but dont know how to fix it.

```
TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: The naive way would just be something like `tileGridSize = tuple(int(sys.argv[3]), int(sys.argv[4]))` to handle your current input. Are you wanting to specify a tuple in the command line, or just group two separate arguments into a tuple?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you look into `argparse` which is the standard package to handle command-lines but using strictly `sys.argv`:

```
import sys


print(sys.argv[1], float(sys.argv[2]), tuple(map(int, sys.argv[3:])))
```

```
$ python testing.py picture.jpg 3.0 8 8
> picture.jpg 3.0 (8, 8)
```

What happens:

- `sys.argv[3:]` gets the list of all args including and after the 4th (index `3`)
- `map(int, sys.argv[3:])` applies the `int` function to all items in the list
- `tuple(...)` transforms `map`'s generator into a proper tuple